# storage.objects().compose() not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using the GCS JSON API via Java. My code to insert objects, delete objects, and copy objects all works great. But for some reason I cannot get storage.objects().compose() to work. No matter what I get a 400 or 500 error. Even when I go to use the "Try it now" feature for compose on the Google website I get the same error. So there must be something basic I am missing.

Here is my code:

```
StorageObject metadata = new StorageObject()
    .setMetadata( ImmutableMap.of("OriginalFileName", originalFileName) )
    .setContentType(contentType)
    .setAcl( ImmutableList.of( new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER") ) );


// list of files to concatenate
List<SourceObjects> sourceObjects = new ArrayList<SourceObjects>();
for (int i = 0; i <= chunkNumber; i++) {
    sourceObjects.add( new SourceObjects().setName(objectName + ".chunk" + i) );
}

ComposeRequest composeReq = new ComposeRequest()
    .setSourceObjects(sourceObjects)
    .setDestination(metadata);


storage.objects().compose(bucketName, objectName, composeReq).execute();
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
 500 { "code" : 500, "errors" : [ 
      { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Backend Error", "reason" : "backendError" } 
      ], "message" : "Backend Error" }
```

Comment: After more hours of trial and error, it appears that you **CANNOT** set an ACL like in the above example when using the compose() method. It works with other methods (insert, copy), but not compose(). Google: you really, really need more informative error messages if you want to save developers from pulling their hair out. "Invalid ACL" or "Invalid Permissions" or anything like that in the error message would have been a huge help.

Comment: Hi user2134059, you don't appear to be doing anything wrong. I will personally investigate this issue and let you know when I have a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Comment: Hello again. I have confirmed that I can reproduce this behavior. We are working on a fix. Thank you for noticing this!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reply. For now, removing the setAcl() portion of the above code and calling storage.objectAccessControls().insert() after the compose seems to be working for me.

Comment: Update: the root cause has been fixed. Your example should work fine now.